# Why does using Array.map(parseInt) on an array of strings produce different results

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, parseint

I was watching a talk on destroy all software title [The Birth and Death of Javascript](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/the-birth-and-death-of-javascript)

during the talk Gary Bernhardt pointed out a JavaScript quirky features, were given an array of integer strings,

```
javascript
var a = ['10','10','10','10']
console.log(a.map(parseInt)); // [10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
```

`Array.map()` takes a function and returns a new array with the result of applying this function on each operator.

I found the behavior incredibly bizarre at first, doesn't `parseInt` parse a number to an integer?

why would it be `NaN`? and then not **10!!**

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad question or answer, but since this is plagiarized right off your blog, I would think about removing the blog spam.

Comment: it's quite understandable, I removed the link, I had mixed feelings about linking to my blog anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript is often the subject of parody, for its seemingly [unexpected results](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

```
var a = []+{} // [Object object]
var b = {}+[] // 0
```

However there is consistency in its madness, and I suspected the `parseInt` behavior must have some reason behind it.

#### Getting to the bottom of what's happening

I first thought of debugging `parseInt`, but since couldn't debug a native function, I thought of wrapping it around another function that basically does the same thing.

```
var a = ['10','10','10','10']
var intParse = function (x) {
    return parseInt(x);
};

console.log(a.map(parseInt)); // [10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(a.map(intParse)); // [10,10,10,10]
```

Ok so it seems like everything is working [fine](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fine&defid=489530)

But just for the sake of brevity I decided to try some more observations

```
var a;

(a = Array(13).join('10,').split(',')).pop()  // try array of 13 '10's
a.map(parseInt); // [10, NaN, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

(a = Array(10).join('100,').split(',')).pop() // try array of 10 '100's
a.map(parseInt); // [100, NaN, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

(a = Array(10).join('7,').split(',')).pop()   // try array of 10 '6's
a.map(parseInt); // [7, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 6, 6, 6]
```

#### Maybe it's not that weird after all

At this point as weird as the results may seem, they are consistent (in some way), there certainly seems to be a pattern.

It then hit me.
`Array.map(callback)` the callback takes 3 parameters, `(key, index, array)`, so what if `parseInt` doesn't just take one parameter but 2 instead.

That would certainly had an effect on its results

[Turns out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.

Syntax
`parseInt(string, radix);`

the **radix** is the base of the number

```
parseInt("10", 0) // 10, zero meant decimal
parseInt("10", 1) // NaN, since only 0 is allowed in base 1
parseInt("10", 2) // 2, '10' in binary
parseInt("10", 3) // 3, '10' in ternary
//...
```

Since the second argument in `map`'s callback is the index the **radix** kept changing according to the index.

This explains why my `intParse` function worked.
I had specifically defined that it uses 'parseInt' with just x.

I thought this was what's happening inside map

```
var intParse = function (x) { return parseInt(x);}
```

When in fact this is what was happening

```
var intParse = function (x, r, array) { return parseInt(x, r);}
```

What I should've done when wrapping the function was
to not assuming the arguments that where being passed like so

```
var a = ['10','10','10','10']
var intParse = function () {
    return parseInt.apply(this, arguments);
}
console.log(a.map(parseInt)); // [10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(a.map(intParse)); // [10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
```

#### Lessons learned

This was a nice exploration, I think I wound up learning a bit more than I thought I would about `parseInt`.

More importantly tho I was reminded that when programs act in an unexpected way, it is most likely for a reason.

Finally, if one wants to properly wrap a function use `.apply(this, arguments)`